# Checker null value of JSON by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement

for example i acquire some json data like below

```
     errorCode: null,
        message: "Success",
        result: {
        keywordData: null, 
        },
       totalRecord: 1,
    checkAccess: true,
   token: xxxxx
```

As you  see the keywordData is null.

And i am having a if statment in my JS like below

```
if(Object.keys(result.keywordData.length !== 0)){

  //do something

}
```

but it's not working, how may i check null value?

**full JSON:**

```
  {
    errorCode: null,
    message: "Success",
    result: {
    keywordData: null,
    keywords: null,
    lastSyncDate: 1465168445000,
    profileId: 129,
    overallTrend: null
    },
    totalRecord: 1,
    checkAccess: true,
    token: "123"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided the full structure of the object, so I'm assuming this is what it looks like:

```
var object = {
    errorCode: null,
    message: "Success",
    result: {
        keywordData: null,
    },
    totalRecord: 1,
    checkAccess: true,
    token: xxxxx
};
```

If this is indeed the structure of the object, then you can simply do this:

```
if (object.result.keywordData) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried to console it and it return error message to me :  Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined

Comment: i can't change the JSON , i got it from bad end

Comment: Could you supply the structure of the full structure of the JSON at least?

Comment: the one i gave out is the full structure

Comment: tried Object.keys(result.keywordData)  but it returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: An object needs to have enclosing braces, otherwise it's not an object and will throw an error. I need to know what variable this JSON output is assigned to in order to give you the correct `if-condition`.

Comment: `Object.keys(result.keywordData)` will give you an error because according to your example `result` is a key _within another object_, so you can't access it without the outer object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113874/discussion-between-blaze-sahlzen-and-anson920520).

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {
  keywordData: null
};

if(a.keywordData !== null) {
  console.log('false');
} else {
  console.log('true');
}
```